# In which book was an anagram of Aldebaran used?

Tags: story-identification

I can't remember the story line of the book but the cover was a uniform yellow and I distinctly remember the main character figuring out that the name of a company was the anagram of Aldebaran [star], perhaps Narabedla. It may even be the title of the book. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean the *star* [Aldebaran](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aldebaran)?

Comment: @gnovice Yes, it is the star now you mention it. That would be a red giant, perhaps the origins of the company.

Comment: this might help: http://wordsmith.org/anagram/anagram.cgi?anagram=alderbaran&t=1000&a=n

Comment: Narabedran isn't an anagram of Aldebaran.

Comment: @randal'thor see answer below :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's probably [*Narabedla, Ltd.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narabedla_Ltd.) by [Frederik Pohl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frederik_Pohl). The name of the alien-owned corporation that the book is titled after is the word [Aldebaran](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aldebaran) (a red giant star in the constellation [Taurus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taurus_%28constellation%29)) spelled backwards.

There are a [number of different cover designs](https://www.librarything.com/work/48856/covers/) for the various printings. Being you're in Belgium, I'm guessing you had gotten a hold of a copy from [Victor Gollancz Ltd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victor_Gollancz_Ltd), a British publishing house (they seemed to like the yellow covers):

[image: Yellow book cover with a white box at the top containing the "Gollancz SF" logotype in orange; a large white box below contains (vertically) "NARADEBLA" "LTD" (in black) "FREDERIK" "POHL" (in orange) and, smaller, "The new novel by the science fiction Grand Master"]